# delegate crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I have delegate

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <DelegateProtocol> delegate;
```

but it crash on performSelector

```
if (_delegate != nil && [_delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(DelegateProtocol)])
{
    NSObject *obj = _delegate;
//HERE IS EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    [obj performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didTouchImageView:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

I set delegate here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [invoiceTabImage setDelegate:self];
}
```

and the question is why it might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means that your delegate was already deallocated when you sent it the message `didTouchImageView` (I assume that everything is ok when you send the message `performSelector`, it would be too easy).

First of all, check the retain/release management for your delegate to see if  there is anything incorrect.

If everything seems ok, one possibility to debug this is enabling Zombies (you can do through Instruments/Run with performance tool, or by setting an environment variable when debugging).

This could help you detect the cause of the problem.

If you need more help, please, post the code about how you create/retain/release your delegate object, and also paste the stack trace of the crash.

EDIT:

Two hints:

1. the key to working with delegates (without retaining them) is ensuring that the view controller (that in your case is also the delegate) lives longer than `invoiceTabImage`; you can then review `invoiceTabImage`'s lifecycle (when it is created/released) and compare it to the delegate's;
2. in your controller's `dealloc`, add this line:

   `invoiceTabImage = nil`;

   so that you are ensuring that when the controller/delegate is removed, the delegating object knows that the delegate is not there anymore; the program will not work, but possibly will not crash.

Comment: +1 99% of the time this is accessing a freed object, look up `NSZombie` for help with these, but if you know it's during delegate access, then that's your problem.

Comment: yes but how to archive it without (retain) delegate? How to do it "right"?

Comment: Thanks. Indeed my custom UIViewController is deallocated right after initialization, even if view is set (with IB) but this is for another question.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if it is being set to nil (which is what dealloc will do).

This solved the problem for me:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<UITableViewDelegate>)newDelegate
    {
        if (newDelegate!=nil) {
            if (newDelegate != self.collapseDelegate)
            {
                self.collapseDelegate = newDelegate;
                [super setDelegate:self.collapseDelegate?self:nil];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ,its Working

Comment: Shouldn't we push this fix? I still see it exists and this condition:
if (newDelegate!=nil) {

doesn't appear in sources.